# COUNT(*) and Having

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gets me a column of distances. 
But what i need is only the count of results with matching distances, not the distances themselves. A Subselect cannot be used.

```
SELECT 
( 6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * cos(0.899945742869) * (sin(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) * sin(0.14286767838) + cos(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) * cos(0.14286767838)) - sin(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * sin(0.899945742869))) ) AS Distance

FROM ...

WHERE ...

HAVING Distance > 0 AND Distance <= 25
```

Comment: Did you just omit the `GROUP BY` in your question or you don't have one at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the distances, only the count, maybe this will work:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM ...
WHERE ... AND
  (6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * cos(0.899945742869) *
  (sin(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) * sin(0.14286767838) + cos(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) *
   cos(0.14286767838)) - sin(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * sin(0.899945742869)))
  ) BETWEEN 0 AND 25
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the `Between` Operator.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to move the distance calculation to the where clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...

WHERE ( 6368 * SQRT(2*(1-...) BETWEEN 0 AND 25
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the totalResults, and you can discard the other column.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) totalResults, 
    ( 6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * cos(0.899945742869) * (sin(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) * sin(0.14286767838) + cos(RADIANS(`loc_lon`)) * cos(0.14286767838)) - sin(RADIANS(loc_lat)) * sin(0.899945742869))) ) AS Distance

    FROM ...

    WHERE ...

    HAVING Distance > 0 AND Distance <= 25
```

Comment: I tried that of course. But that gets my an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).